# Multidimensional matrix multiplication on numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, machine-learning, neural-network

I'm implementing a neural network in python, as a part of backpropagation I need to multiply a 3D matrix,call it A, dimension `(200, 100, 1)` , by a 2D matrix, call it W,dimension `(100, 200)` the result should have dimensions `(200, 200, 1)`.

A is an error vector, W is a weight matrix, the product is to be used to calculate the updates for the previous layer.

I tried solving it using `matrix_multiply`(`from numpy.core.umath_tests`), I tried reshaping W to (100,200,1) and then multiplying, but that throws

`ValueError: matrix_multiply: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (m,n),(n,p)->(m,p) (size 100 is different from 1)`.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Do you have a compelling reason for keeping the shape of `A` as (200, 100, 1), instead of dropping the trivial dimension and making its shape (200, 100)?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser I didn't consider that option. Thanks for the suggestion, I'll explore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [`np.tensordot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.tensordot.html) and then permute axes with `swapaxes` or simply `reshape` -

```
np.tensordot(A,W,axes=((1),(0))).swapaxes(1,2)
np.tensordot(A,W,axes=((1),(0))).reshape(A.shape[0],W.shape[1],1)
```

Alternatively, we can use [`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html) using the only slice along the last axis of `A` and then after matrix-multiplication extend into `3D` -

```
A[:,:,0].dot(W)[...,None]
```

Or we can use [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
np.einsum('ijk,jl->ilk',A,W)
```